# Call functions in Truffle as different account

Tags: truffle, testing, unittesting

I'm trying to create some unit tests in Truffle to call functions in a contract as a different account, so I can properly test the contract. I can do this in javascript with { from: account } but I'd like to keep my tests in Solidity. How can I do it?